# How to group by date with postgreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have an array of dates

```
[Thu, 06 Feb 2014, Mon, 10 Feb 2014, Mon, 10 Feb 2014, Mon, 10 Feb 2014, Mon, 10 Feb 2014, Mon, 10 Feb 2014, Mon, 10 Feb 2014, Mon, 10 Feb 2014, Mon, 10 Feb 2014, Mon, 10 Feb 2014, Mon, 10 Feb 2014, Mon, 10 Feb 2014, Mon, 10 Feb 2014, Mon, 10 Feb 2014, Mon, 10 Feb 2014, Tue, 11 Feb 2014, Wed, 12 Feb 2014, Wed, 12 Feb 2014, Wed, 12 Feb 2014, Thu, 13 Feb 2014, Thu, 13 Feb 2014, Fri, 14 Feb 2014, Fri, 14 Feb 2014, Fri, 14 Feb 2014, Fri, 14 Feb 2014, Fri, 14 Feb 2014, Fri, 14 Feb 2014, Fri, 14 Feb 2014]
```

Which was created like so:

```
votes.find(:all, order: :created_at).map{|v| v.created_at.to_date }
```

How do I count how many votes where created per day?

Answer (score 1):

Why not

```
Votes.order("to_char(created_at,'MM/DD/YYYY')").group("to_char(created_at,'MM/DD/YYYY')").select("to_char(created_at,'MM/DD/YYYY') as creation, Count(votes.id) as vote_count")
```

This will return an ActiveRecord::Relation containing the creation date as MM/DD/YYYY (you can obviously change this format to match yours which is `'Dy, DD Mon YYYY'`)  and the count of votes on that date. These attributes would be accessible through the methods `creation` and `vote_count`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it directly using the sql query:

```
Vote.order(:created_at).group("date(created_at)").count
```

Also:

```
Vote.order(:created_at).group("to_char(created_at, 'YYYY/MM/DD')").count
```

Comment: `DATE_FORMAT` is not a `postgresql` function and this will just give him the number of days where votes where cast. He wants the number of votes per day. Also to order by :created_at it would have to be included in the `GROUP BY` clause as well

Comment: Edited adapting mysql `DATE_FORMAT` to postgresql `to_char`. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately your methodology still only outputs the number of days votes were cast not the number of votes per day which is what the OP requested. Your saying group all the days together and then report the count of these groups which will equal the number of distinct days in `votes.created_at`